# What is $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$?

Tags: notation, p-adic-number-theory

What is $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ ?

I think $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of p-adic integers but not sure what the * represents.

Comment: In general, given a ring $R$, we define $R^*$ to be its group of units (invertible elements). In this case, $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is the set of elements not divisible by $p$.

Comment: so you seem to be saying  that being invertible in this ring is equivalent to not being divisible by $p$. So all numbers divisible by $p$ are not invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The star usually refers to the group of units of a ring $R$. Another notation is $U(R)$.

Comment: Congrats on the 50k ☺️

Answer (score 1):

It's the group of $ p $-adic units.