# What is $\mathbb{Z}^*_2$

Tags: notation, p-adic-number-theory

What is $\displaystyle{\mathbb{Z}^*_2}$?

Do I understand correctly it's the odd numbers?  It would appear it includes both positive and negative.

$\displaystyle{\mathbb{Z}^*_2}=2\mathbb{Z}-1$

Sorry - to clarify.  I was told $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is the group of units of the ring of p-adics, and that this meant the set of numbers not divisible by $p$.

So this question is to test whether I understand correctly.  The explanation given would seem to imply that $\mathbb{Z}_2^*$ is the set of 2-adic integers not divisible by $2$, so the odd numbers.  Is the explanation given to me incorrect, or did I misinterpret it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does not have very much to do with Laurent series anyway. Cough cough.

Comment: Maybe it refers to $\{[1]\}$, where $[1]=\{x\in\Bbb Z: x\equiv 1\mod 2\}$

Comment: I would think it's the trivial group of one element.

Comment: The Laurent Series tag is puzzling, there seems to be no connection.  The P-adic tag suggests that possibly you mean non-zero $2$-adic integers.  Or  did you just pick tags at random?

Comment: @lulu: I suppose it would be the _invertible_ 2-adic integers -- e.g. $2=\ldots00010_2$ is nonzero, but shouldn't be in $\mathbb Z_2^\times$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Agreed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm clarification added to the question hopefully ^^

Comment: @lulu I've clarified in the question what I meant. If I understood correctly what I was told then I was trying describe the primes of the 2-adics, which I thought meant the 2-adics not divisible by $2$ but it's possible I misunderstood the notation. Anyhow, If Z_p is the p-adics and Z_p^* is the primes of the ring of p-adics, then can I notate the primes of the 2-adics as I have done and what are they? The Laurent series tag is because every p-adic number is a finite-tailed Laurent series.

Comment: So you do mean the invertible  $2$-adic integers.  As others have remarked, the notation is unfortunately ambiguous.  And, yes, any actual integer is invertible in $\mathbb Z_2$ iff it is odd.  But there are more invertible $2$-adic integers than that.  Every rational $\frac ab$ with $a,b$ both odd, is an invertible $2$-adic integer, for example.

Comment: @lulu would that still be considered an integer if $b$ did not divide $a$?

Comment: I wrote out some details below...I'm not sure what you mean by "integer" in that comment.  To me, saying "integer" suggests $\mathbb Z$.  That sits inside the $p$-adics by looking at sequences which become constant at some point (using the notation of my post).  To your specific comment:  $\frac 35$ is certainly a $2$-adic integer, though it is clearly not an "integer".

Comment: $2$ is the only prime (up to unit multiple) in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, so it is a bit misleading to talk about  primes of the ring of $p$-adic integers. There are also other apparent misconceptions. What does hold is that $\Bbb{Z}_2^*\cap \Bbb{Z}$ consists exactly of the odd integers. In other words
$$2\Bbb{Z}-1\subset \Bbb{Z}_2^*.$$ If we intersect $\Bbb{Z}_2^*$ with $\Bbb{Q}$, then we get the set
$$\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{Z}_2^*=\{\frac pq\mid p,q\in\Bbb{Z},\ \text{both odd}\}.$$ But, there are uncountably many $2$-adic integers, and uncountably many units as well.

Comment: We do have
$$\Bbb{Z}_2^*=\Bbb{Z}_2\setminus 2\Bbb{Z}_2.$$ 
This means that $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is a local ring, and $2\Bbb{Z}_2$ is its unique maximal ideal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen now you've really thrown me. I thought p-adics were a way of expressing rational numbers only, which I thought would imply they are countable!

Comment: Robert, the series expansion of $2$-adic integers says that they are entities of the form
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n2^n,$$ with $b_n\in\{0,1\}$ for all $n$. That is, countably infinitely many coefficients to choose, two alternatives for each. $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the continuum cardinality.

Comment: May be you were mislead by having seen the description of the $p$-adic metric between two rational numbers? That is, indeed, a useful way of introducing the $p$-adics. But, to get all the $p$-adic numbers we need to go to the completion of the metric space. The same way we get the real numbers by completing $\Bbb{Q}$ with respect to the absolute value metric.

Comment: Too many comments already, but the $2$-adic integer ring $\Bbb Z_2$ definitely contains more than rational numbers: in fact, they enjoy the benefits of Hensel’s Lemma, which tells you, for instance, that $\sqrt{-7}$ and $\sqrt[3]3$ are in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for clarifying. It was the fact the metric space is Cauchy within Q that led me to believe the domain was within Q but now I understand 'completion' better thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170832/what-is-mathbbz-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any prime $p$, the $p$-adic integers can be thought of as a sequence of integers $\alpha=\{a_0,a_1,\cdots\}$ satisfying $a_n\equiv a_{n-1}\pmod {p^n}$ for all $n≥1$.

These form a ring under component-wise addition and multiplication.  We'll call that ring $\mathbb Z_p$.

With $p=2$, your question is equivalent to:

Claim:  $\alpha$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z_p$ if and only if $a_0\not \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Proof:

Suppose $\alpha$ is a unit. Then there is a $p$-adic integer $\beta=\{b_n\}$ with $\alpha\times \beta =1 $ In particular we have $a_0\times b_0\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so $a_0$ can't be divisible by $p$.

Now suppose that $a_0 \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$.  Then we can find $b_0$ with $a_0\times b_0\equiv 1 \pmod p$. By the definition of the $p$-adic integers we know that $a_i\not \equiv 0 \pmod p\;\forall i$ as well, so we can always solve $a_n\times b_n\equiv 1 \pmod {p^{n+1}}$ and it is easy to see that the $b_n$ so constructed define a $p$-adic integer $\beta$ with $\alpha \times \beta =1$.

Comment: sorry, just to be clear, you're saying it's the odd numbers?

Comment: Well, they aren't all actual integers.  The sequence $\{1,1,3,3+4,3+8,\cdots, \}$ defines an invertible $2$-adic integer, but it isn't an actual integer.  If you are asking about $\mathbb Z_2^*\cap \mathbb Z$ then, yes...these are the odd integers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we denote

$$\mathbb Z_n:=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z,$$

and when $A$ is a ring,

$$A^\times:=\{a\in A,\ a\text{ is invertible in }A\}.$$

So

$$\mathbb Z_n^\times=\{k\in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \ \gcd(k,n)=1\}.$$

In your case,

$$\mathbb Z_2^\times=\{k\in \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z, \ \gcd(k,2)=1\}=\{1\}.$$

Comment: This is probably not the meaning of $\mathbb Z_n$ that's in play here, given that the question is tagged [tag:p-adic-number-theory].

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, but since there was also a tag *Laurent series*, I assumed the tags were kind of randoms.

Comment: @E.Joseph Thanks for your answer.  Every p-adic number is a finite-tailed Laurent series, apparently.  All things are *kind of* of random, although nothing is *entirely* random!  So what I meant to notate was the units of the 2-adic integers, if that makes sense.  I was told $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is the p-adics not divisible by $p,$ so I wanted to check I understood correctly whether $\mathbb{Z}_2^*$ is the set of p-adics not divisible by $2$.